# Add and remove and add a class for multiple inputs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to remove a class with the same input class. Its basically a form validation, but I have a dynamic form with inputs that can be added and deleted. So with those dynamic fields, im trying to add and delete classes depending on a submit.

This is what I have:

```
var i_id = $("#i_id");
var choosec = $("#choose_c");

$('#submit').click(function(e){
    if (choosec.val() == "none"){
        choosec.addClass("inputerror");
        $("#c-error").removeClass("hide-error");
        $("#c-error").addClass("show-error");
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        choosec.removeClass("inputerror");
        $("#c-error").removeClass("show-error");
        $("#c-error").addClass("hide-error");
    }

    if (i_id.val() == "" || i_id.val().length < 7){
        i_id.addClass("inputerror");
        $("#i-error").removeClass("hide-error");
        $("#i-error").addClass("show-error");
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        i_id.removeClass("inputerror");
        $("#i-error").removeClass("show-error");
        $("#i-error").addClass("hide-error");
    }

    $(".qty").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).is(':enabled')){
            $(this).addClass("inputerror");
            $("#qty-error").removeClass("hide-error");
            $("#qty-error").addClass("show-error");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("inputerror");
            $("#qty-error").removeClass("show-error");
            $("#qty-error").addClass("hide-error");
        }
    });

    $(".name").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).is(':enabled')){
            $(this).addClass("inputerror");
            $("#name-error").removeClass("hide-error");
            $("#name-error").addClass("show-error");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("inputerror");
            $("#name-error").removeClass("show-error");
            $("#name-error").addClass("hide-error");
        }
    });

    $(".price").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).is(':enabled') || $(this).val() == "0" && $(this).is(':enabled')){
            $(this).addClass("inputerror");
            $("#price-error").removeClass("hide-error");
            $("#price-error").addClass("show-error");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("inputerror");
            $("#price-error").removeClass("show-error");
            $("#price-error").addClass("hide-error");
        }
    });

    $(".subtotal").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "" && $(this).is(':enabled') || $(this).val() == "0.00" && $(this).is(':enabled')){
            $(this).addClass("inputerror");
            $("#sub-error").removeClass("hide-error");
            $("#sub-error").addClass("show-error");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("inputerror");
            $("#sub-error").removeClass("show-error");
            $("#sub-error").addClass("hide-error");
        }
    });

});
```

for the qty, name, price and subtotal class. The errors aren't showing. Any ideas?

Comment: i can't find chooseclient variable in your script? also (choosec.val() == "none") . "none" is default value for choosec?

Comment: Did you try adding `console.log()` statements to see if the code is actually executed as expected? Also without the corresponding HTML it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

This variable? Have you declare this?

```
chooseclient.removeClass("inputerror");
```

Comment: I don't see any problem based on the script anymore. Problem should be on the html. You should provide them. And I think you should make 2 functions like AddError(obj, errmsg) and RemoveError(obj), to clean your script a bit, avoiding repetitive codes.